# Check boolean jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I create a forms with html/css and i validate my forms with javascript/jquery.

If valid equal false, validate is work. But if i want check if valid equal true, i have no error but my function is not execute.

here my form

```
        <div class="success-message"></div>
        <br>

        <label for="login">Login :</label>
        <input type="text" id="login" value="" />
        <span class="error-message">error</span>
        <br>
```

and here my validate function

```
$("#envoyer").click(function(){
    valid = true;

        //LOGIN VALIDATE
        if($("#login").val() == ""){
            $("#login").next(".error-message").fadeIn().text("Please enter your login");
            valid = false;
        }
        else if (!$("#login").val().match(/^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]+$/gim)){
            $("#login").next(".error-message").fadeIn().text("Please enter a valid login");
            valid = false;
        }
        else{
            $("#login").next(".error-message").fadeOut();
        }


        if(valid == true){
            console.log(valid);
            (".success-message").fadeIn().text("The form is sent with success");
        }

        return valid

});
```

When i send my form and there is no error, i see with console.log() valid equal "true" but my div "sucess-message" not appear.

i add "$" but i have a same problem

thanks

Comment: you are missing the $ in front of $(".success-message")

Comment: Check your error console.  You will find a complaint about a syntax error on the `(".success-message")` line because you omitted the `$` !

Comment: [**How to use the console**](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: Question should be closed for "simple typographical error" reason.

Comment: @VDesign he sets `valid = true` on the first line so the only possible values are `true` and `false` and a simple `if (valid)` test would be perfectly appropriate.

Comment: The variable `valid` should be declared with `var`.

Comment: i add "$" in front of my message, but i have a same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Missing a `$` in front of `(".success-message").fadeIn().text("The form is sent with success");`

It's always the simple things :)

Comment: you do have access to the "close this question because it was just a typo" option, don't you?

Comment: I didn't even know I can flag a question. Neat! Will do

Comment: It's not a flag, it's a "close vote" option.  possibly you only get it at 3k rep, which ironically you're now only 1 point away from getting.